# Google Sheets Query to combine data from 3 sheets with different criteria

Tags: google-sheets

I need to combine 3 sets of data vertically, using a Query. The first 2 data sources ('SOURCE 1'!A:T and EG:EZ) have the same conditions and I was able to combine them with no problem, but the 3rd data source ('SOURCE 3'!A:T) has different conditions and when I add this source I result in an error. The column headers will be identical in the output.

This is the formula containing ONLY the first 2 data sources, that works:

```
=QUERY({'SOURCE 1'!A:T;EG:EZ},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col10 >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col10 <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col20 = 'YES' and Col1 starts with 'APP-' order by Col2,Col10,Col1,Col9 label Col11 'NAME'",1)
```

When adding in the 3rd data source, below are the 3 formulas I've tried, but all result in the error:
***In ARRAY_LITERAL, an Array Literal was missing values for one or more rows.***

Attempt 1:

```
={QUERY({'SOURCE 1'!A:T;EG:EZ},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col10 >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col10 <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col20 = 'YES' and Col1 starts with 'APP-' order by Col2,Col10,Col1,Col9 label Col11 'NAME'",1);
QUERY('SOURCE 3'!A:T,"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col1 is not null")}
```

Attempt 2:

```
={QUERY('SOURCE 1'!A:T,"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col10 >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col10 <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col20 = 'YES' and Col1 starts with 'APP-' order by Col2,Col10,Col1,Col9 label Col11 'NAME'",1);
QUERY(EG:EZ,"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col10 >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col10 <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col20 = 'YES' and Col1 starts with 'APP-' order by Col2,Col10,Col1,Col9 label Col11 'NAME'");
QUERY('SOURCE 3'!A:T,"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col16,' ',Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col1 is not null")}
```

Attempt 3:

```
={QUERY('SOURCE 1'!A:T,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where J >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and T = 'YES' and A starts with 'APP-' order by B,J,A,I label K 'NAME'",1);
QUERY(EG:EZ,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M where J >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and J <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and T = 'YES' and A starts with 'APP-' order by B,J,A,I");
QUERY('SOURCE 3'!A:T,"Select A,B,C,D,E,P,' ',H,I,J,K,L,M where A is not null")}
```

Any advice would be much appreciated. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you write `QUERY(EG:EZ,"Select A,B,C,D,E,F,G,H,I,J,K,L,M` you can't select A... within EG:EZ!

I suggest to change `'SOURCE 1'!A:T` by `{'SOURCE 1'!A:T}` , idem for `EG:EZ` and then you will be able to use only Col1, Col2 etc. in your formula.

Try

```
={QUERY({'SOURCE 1'!A:T},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col10 >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col10 <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col20 = 'YES' and Col1 starts with 'APP-' order by Col2,Col10,Col1,Col9 label Col11 'NAME'",1);
QUERY({EG:EZ},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col6,Col7,Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col10 >= date '"&TEXT(B1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col10 <= date '"&TEXT(D1,"yyyy-mm-dd")&"' and Col20 = 'YES' and Col1 starts with 'APP-' order by Col2,Col10,Col1,Col9 label Col11 'NAME'");
QUERY({'SOURCE 3'!A:T},"Select Col1,Col2,Col3,Col4,Col5,Col16,' ',Col8,Col9,Col10,Col11,Col12,Col13 where Col1 is not null")}
```

if there is a lack of data in one of the three queries, you will also get an error, in that case, add `iferror(query______,{"","","",...}` on each query